# Liquibase and JAR dependencies

Tags: liquibase

I'm new to Liquibase but I've got it set up and it's working OK for me, but I've manually downloaded all dependent JAR files to get it working.

Now I want to set up a pom.xml and let Maven worry about downloading dependences. For some reason I can't get that to work at all. Maven runs and finds what it thinks are all the dependencies, but then Liquibase immediately crashes every time it starts. With version 3.5.5 up through 3.8.0 it crashes with NoClassDefFoundError on org/slf4j/LoggerFactory; on 3.8.1 and above it fails with the same error on ch/qos/logback/core/Context. I've triple-checked my classpath settings and I'm sure they are correct.

So my question is this: Fundamentally, should it be possible to set up a dependency  on liquibase-core in a pom.xml file, let Maven download all dependencies, and use those and only those dependencies in the java call (other than the JDBC driver, of course)?

Everything I know about Maven tells me that this should work, but I've been trying for hours and for the life of me cannot get Liquibase to work with the dependent JARs which Maven downloads. And strangely, it does seem to download the JARs I would have expected are missing: slf4j-api (1.7.25) and logback-core (1.2.3). but for whatever reason it seems to be calling methods which aren't defined in them (version skew somehow?).

Here is my "pom.xml" file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
   <artifactId>myapp-lib</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                   <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                   <version>3.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>
                    GetLiquibaseJars
                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>GetLiquibaseJars</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                    <type>[ packaging ]</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${MYAPP_ROOT}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
   </build>
 </project>
```

When run, that downloads:

```
jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar
logback-core-1.2.3.jar
```

so logback-core is available. Here's my Java call:

```
java -classpath "/home/myself/proj/my_app/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:\
/home/myself/proj/my_app/lib/liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:\
/home/myself/proj/my_app/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:\
/home/myself/proj/my_app/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:\
/home/myself/proj/my_app/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar" \
-jar /home/myself/proj/my_app/lib/liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar \
--classpath=/home/myself/proj/my_app/links/sybase-linux/jConnect-6_0/classes/jconn3.jar \
--url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:mydbserver.mycompany.com:1234 \
--defaultSchemaName=dbo --username=my_user \
--password=my_pwd \
--changeLogFile=/home/myself/proj/my_app/db/changelog.xml \
--logLevel=info status
```

The exception I get is:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/Context
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.Context
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I've confirmed the jar file are readable, and as far as I can tell this "Context" class is defined in logback-core v1.2.3.

Update: Interestingly, if I replace the "-jar /home/myself/proj/my_app/lib/liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar" with a call to the Main, i.e. "liquibase.integration.commandline.Main", it works fine. But calling the main Liquibase core JAR file as a runnable jar with "-jar" seems to cause Java to completely ignore the entire classpath, and crash on the first external dependency it sees.

Comment: show us your pom.xml

Comment: Have you followed the example at https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/creating-liquibase-projects-with-maven-postgreSQL.html ?

Comment: the pom.xml is trivial -- it defines a dummy project and the one dependency on liquibase-core. I did manage to get it working with version 3.5.5 but that had only two dependent JARs. I'll post my pom.xml on Monday when I'm back at work.